# Concatenate hyperlinks to one cell without losing hyperlink properties

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 3 website addresses that I would like to combine into one cell separated by a comma using only a script. I collect my URL's using the snipet of code below. The variable j is just a counter from a previous loop which counts the number of rows.

```
    for (var k = 1; k < j+1; k++) {
  var A = sheet.getRange(k, 2, 1, 1).getValues();
  var A = A[0][0];

  var B = sheet.getRange(k, 3, 1, 1).getValues();
  var B = B[0][0];

  var C = sheet.getRange(k, 4, 1, 1).getValues();
  var C = C[0][0];

  var D = [A, B, C];

  //sheet.getRange(k,5,1,1).setValues(D);
  var E = A + ", " + B + ", " + C;
  sheet.getRange(k,5,1,1).setValue(E);
}
```

I get the combined links except that they lose their hyperlink property, it just appears as text.[image: combined links]. As shown in the image, the contents in the last cell contain all the hyperlinks but it is only text.

Comment: When you do this via the UI manually, do the hyperlinks remain clickable? If not, then doing it via Script / API won't help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess concatenation does not work with multiple links. I just solved my problem after further experimentation. I don't actually need the concatenation to preserve the hyperlink properties as I originally thought. I'm using my script to basically collect a group of hyperlinks to use as file attachments in the Mail Merge addon. Mail Merge does not require the File Attachments cells to be hyperlinks. I guess the code behind this splits the cell string with a comma as the delimiter as uses each separate text (http link) as the attachment hyperlink.

Comment: You are right, Google Sheets doesn't allow multiple hyperlinks on a single cell.